# Why can I combine a bitwise operator with a math operator, like &+, in Java?

Tags: java, operators

I was writing some code earlier today, and forgot I was writing Java instead of Swift and accidentally typed `&+`. Surprisingly, I didn't get any errors, and the code compiled and ran fine.

I played around a little bit, and found that `&+`, `&-`, `|+`, `|-`, `^+`, and `^-` all compile and run without errors. It looks like they all act like the first bitwise operator when acting on numbers:

```
1 &+ 2 == 1 & 2
3 |+ 4 == 3 | 4
7 ^+ 9 == 7 ^ 9
```

On the other hand, it seems like any other combination of a bitwise operator and a math operator, like `+&`, `&/`, and `^*`, all give compile-time errors.

Why do `&+`, `&-`, `|+`, `|-`, `^+`, and `^-` compile and run without errors? Do they have some purpose that I'm not seeing, or is it just some compilation oddity?

Comment: You're just formatting it wrong. `1 &+ 2` is actually `1 & +2`. You can prefix any number with a `+` or `-`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `+` stands for the [`Unary Plus Operator +`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.3) resulting in a positive number.

The `-` means the [`Unary Minus Operator -`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.4) resulting in a negative number.

- `1 &+ 2` is `1 & +2`
- `3 |- 4` is `3 | -4`
- `7 ^+ 9` is `7 ^ +9`

Notice that `*` and `/` operators cannot be used in the same way (`1 &/ 2`).

Comment: To name it correctly, the `+` sign is an [Unary Plus Operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.3), and the `-` is an [Unary Minus Operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.4).

Comment: Just also to point out, for interest's sake: there is no such thing as a negative integer literal. It's the unary minus operator and a non-negative integer literal. You can see this because you can't write `-2147483648`, even though that is ostensibly equal to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, because it is interpreted as `-` then `2147483648`, which is too large for an int literal.